# Jerk in animation using morphTargets in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I have centred the geometry using geometry.center(); and also centred the morphtargets by holding all vertices of morphTargets in a variable. Now the model loads fine at the center but while playing animation,the animation is not working as expected.Without centring the morphtargets vertices my animation is as expected but there is a jerk at first time step and model is moving to original position(actual loading position) and animating there.

after reading morphTargets:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
for(i=0;i<geometry.morphTargets.length;i++)
{
    geom = geometry.morphTargets[i].vertices;
    geom.center();//with it,the animation plays weird
    geometry.morphTargets.vertices[i] = geom;
    geom.dispose();
}
```

I have animation(playforward,playbackward)
In play forward:

```
render(){
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta = clock.getDelta();
morphs=[];
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.morphTargets.length; i++) {
morphs = geometry.morphTargets[ i ];
morphs.updateAnimation(1000 * delta);
}
}
```

Help me in this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls post code, people can only guess without it

Comment: I have edited and added code.
Kindly look at it.